# Powerful and easy-to-setup mock framework for Java

Tags: open-source, java, software-testing, unit-tests, mocks

I have implemented a Java class that performs calls to an interface that I will call "*TheInterface*".

To unit test my program, I need a mock implementation of TheInterface that I can make my class call. I then need to check whether my class called TheInterface with the correct parameters.

Requirements:

- Can create mocks dynamically, eliminating the need to write mock classes manually
- Syntax as short and understandable as possible
- Make it easy to *assert* what the call's parameters were
- Can be configured to log all calls
- Any method of TheInterface can be dynamically set to return a given result or exception, potentially depending on the call parameters
- Compatible with JUnit
- Open source